# Ошибка в PyAudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

Ubuntu 22.04. Интерпретатор - IDLE (мне так удобнее). PyAudio 0.2.13 (пробовал также на 0.2.11). PyAudio импортируется без ошибок. Код проверял на python 3.7.16 и python 3.10.6. На python 3.7 код работает без ошибок. В python 3.10 ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/idlelib/run.py", line 578, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 24, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 585, in write
    pa.write_stream(self._stream, frames, num_frames,
SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats
```

Вот код, который проигрывает звук микрофона:

```py
import pyaudio

chunk_size = 1024
audio_format = pyaudio.paInt16
channels = 1
rate = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream_in = p.open(format=audio_format,
    channels=channels,
    rate=rate,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=chunk_size)

stream_out = p.open(format=audio_format,
    channels=channels,
    rate=rate,
    output=True,
    frames_per_buffer=chunk_size)

while True:
    data = stream_in.read(chunk_size)
    stream_out.write(data)
```

P.S. 1. Пробовал перед импортированием добавлять (не помогло):

```py
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
import pyaudio
```

2. Пробовал указывать (не помогло)

```py
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, 
                channels=1,
                rate=44100,
                output=True)
```